# Opening Uber app via deeplink (uber://) doesn't use the pick-up and drop-off location parameters

Tags: uber-api

We've got an iOS and Android app where we plan a trip, with the possibility to open the Uber app to request an Uber. As you already entered your pick-up and drop-off location, we use the "Standard Deep Links" functionality (see link (A) below). We pass the pick-up and drop-off location by the parameters described in the Uber documentation.

Since a while, the Uber app doesn't use the pick-up and drop-off location parameters anymore. For instance the following link just opens the Uber app and doesn't pre-select the trip.

```
uber://?action=setPickup&client_id=<CLIENT_ID_FROM_DEVELOPER_DASHBOARD>&pickup[latitude]=52.3876077&pickup[longitude]=4.626904&dropoff[latitude]=52.3880485&dropoff[longitude]=4.6387838
```

Can anyone from the Uber developer team look in to this? Why is this link not working anymore?

Thanks in advance!

(A) https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/deep-links/introduction#standard-deep-links

Answer (score 0):

You can use this website to generate a deeplink: https://developer.uber.com/products/ride-requests-deeplink

Afterwards just replace `https://m.uber.com/ul/` with `uber://`