# DeepLinking stopped navigating to uber native android application

Tags: android, uber-api

I have integrated uber ride request deep linking through RideRequestDeeplink it was working fine until now. But the issue of the redirection has occurred from the past 2 days. I have followed uber developer docs. Deeplink.Fallback.MOBILE_WEB has stopped working.
Does anyone face similar issues?

```
RideRequestDeeplink deeplink = new RideRequestDeeplink.Builder(context)
                    .setSessionConfiguration(config)
                    .setRideParameters(rideParams)
                    .setFallback(Deeplink.Fallback.MOBILE_WEB)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the package manager and pass a properly formatted URI.

You can find more info about how to create the URI here: [Opening Uber app via deeplink (uber://) doesn't use the pick-up and drop-off location parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57038944/opening-uber-app-via-deeplink-uber-doesnt-use-the-pick-up-and-drop-off-loc/57382975#57382975)